# Function returning a results set and an integer in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I'm facing a quite annoying barrier enforced by SQL Server and would like to check if there is an elegant solution for this.

I have a sequence of procedures' invocations (meaning, A calls B which calls C). The procedures are due to return different results sets, where (for instance) "A" generates its result using a set of records returned by "B".

Now, SQL Server does not allow to have nested `INSERT INTO ... EXEC <stored procedure>` so, to cope with this limitation, I converted the lowest procedure into a function that returns a table and hence `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM <function call>`.

Now, there are situations in which the **FUNCTION** cannot return a result due to conditions of the data, and I would like the function to return a sort of **code** indicating the result of the execution (e.g. `0` would mean success, `1` would mean "missing input data").

Since SQL Server does not allow functions with `OUTPUT` parameters, I can't think of any *elegant* way of conveying these two outputs.

Can anyone suggest an *elegant* alternative?

Comment: check @@rowcount after insert and if count is <>0 than success else failed

Comment: Than you @RahulRichhariya for your response, but it is not enough. I simplified the description but in the real case there are several different conditions that may prevent the function to perform its task, and I would like to return one out of different numbers, each specifying which condition took place (e.g. `0` would mean "SUCCESS", `1` would mean "MISSING DATA X", `2` would mean "MISSING DATA Y", etc.).

Comment: not sure but you can explore SET CONTEXT_INFO & context_info column in sys.dm_exec_sessions to achieve this.

Comment: @RahulRichhariya, hummmm... this looks like a _back-door_ approach and hence far from being **_ELEGANT_** I'm afraid.

Comment: you could let the table the function returns contain a result column, and than always return at least one row (the first row) where only that result column is filled (or other result fields if needed). So if no data than the table has one row, if 2 rows of data then the table has 3 rows, and so on...

Comment: @GuidoG, yes, that was one of the alternatives I considered, but its ugliness is beyond my capabilities to absorb. Still, I'm up-voting your suggestion. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

> there are situations in which the FUNCTION cannot return a result due
>   to conditions of the data, and I would like the function to return a
>   sort of code indicating the result of the execution

You really should use THROW to indicate the result of execution, which also precludes using a table-valued function.

So you need to use a stored procedure.  To avoid the restriction on nested INSERT .. SELECT you can use temporary tables to pass data back to the calling procedure.  EG

```
create or alter procedure foo
as
begin
  if object_id('tempdb..#foo_results') is null
  begin
     print 'create table #foo_results(id int primary key, a int);';
     THROW 51000, 'The results table #foo_results does not exist.  Before calling this procedure create it. ', 1;  
  end

  insert into #foo_results(id,a)
  values (1,1);


end;
```

> > Can anyone suggest an ELEGANT alternative?

I'm not sure any of the alternatives is elegant.

Comment: from what version of sql server is the `create or alter` syntax valid ?

Comment: `create or alter` was introduced with SQL 2016 SP1.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, many thanks for your suggestion. I normally (just a matter or taste) leave exceptions handling to that, meaning exceptions that I don't handle within my code. Still, a not elegant but not too ugly solution. I'm up-voting for the idea though will not mark it as THE solution till I decide. Thanks!!!